# List files inside Download directory in android

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am creating my own application for android and I have a problem. I need to get a list of all files from the downloads directory, I tried to do it like this:

```
String path = mContext.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).toString();

                File fl  = new File(path);
                File[] files = fl.listFiles();
                Log.i("File", String.valueOf(files.length));

                for(int i = 0; i < files.length; i++)
                {
                    Log.i("Files", files[i].getName());
                }
```

But it shows me that there are no files in this directory, although there are files there. In advance, I can say that I added permission to the manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

And it still shows me that there are no files in this directory, maybe someone can tell me how to solve this problem. (I'm using android 11 device)

Comment: And you did not tell that you used an Android 11 device.

Comment: Aha . As Mayor Gupta said: getExternalStoragePublicDirectory. But that will still not do on an Android 11 device.

Comment: @blackapps yes, getExternalStoragePublicDirectory will not work because it is deprecated in thi android version

Comment: Indeed deprecated. But working fine. (Well to a certain level). Now do you want to list the files or what? Otherwise query the MediaStore.

Comment: @blackapps yes, I want to list a files

Comment: Well then list them. What is the problem?

Comment: @blackapps As far as I know, when using the mediastore, it uses the mime type. And if the files that are there are not Mime types, how will it show them?

Comment: Why dont you first use the code you posted?

Answer (score 2):

For reading, you just need `Read` permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

And for getting download directory you can use `getExternalStoragePublicDirectory` as following:

```
private void listFiles() {

        File fl = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
        File[] files = fl.listFiles();
        Log.i("File", String.valueOf(files.length));

        for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            Log.i("Files", files[i].getName());
        }
    }
```

Comment: but getExternalStoragePublicDirectory is deprecated